# How to troubleshoot Node/React deployment to Heroku, blank screen issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my Node/React app on Heroku using the Heroku CLI. When I push to Heroku the build succeeds. However, when I go to https://dan-rose.herokuapp.com/ only the header is being rendered and none of my React components. When I enter `heroku logs --tail` I get this message:

```text
$ heroku logs --tail
2022-07-19T05:21:11.858542+00:00 app[web.1]: extname: [Function: extname],
2022-07-19T05:21:11.858542+00:00 app[web.1]: format: [Function: bound _format],
2022-07-19T05:21:11.858543+00:00 app[web.1]: parse: [Function: parse],
2022-07-19T05:21:11.858543+00:00 app[web.1]: sep: '\\',
2022-07-19T05:21:11.858543+00:00 app[web.1]: delimiter: ';',
2022-07-19T05:21:11.858544+00:00 app[web.1]: win32: [Circular *1],
2022-07-19T05:21:11.858544+00:00 app[web.1]: posix: [Circular *2],
2022-07-19T05:21:11.858544+00:00 app[web.1]: _makeLong: [Function: toNamespacedPath]
2022-07-19T05:21:11.858545+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-07-19T05:21:11.858545+00:00 app[web.1]: posix: [Circular *2],
2022-07-19T05:21:11.858545+00:00 app[web.1]: _makeLong: [Function: toNamespacedPath]
2022-07-19T05:21:11.858545+00:00 app[web.1]: }

2022-07-19T05:22:10.223457+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2022-07-19T05:22:10.226458+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2022-07-19T05:22:11.034631+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2022-07-19T05:22:11.217573+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2022-07-19T05:22:12.860897+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`     
2022-07-19T05:22:14.610932+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-07-19T05:22:14.610945+00:00 app[web.1]: > mywebsite@1.0.0 start
2022-07-19T05:22:14.610946+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2022-07-19T05:22:14.610946+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-07-19T05:22:14.802182+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/client/public
2022-07-19T05:22:14.802635+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/client/build
2022-07-19T05:22:14.802665+00:00 app[web.1]: /app
2022-07-19T05:22:14.805418+00:00 app[web.1]: Server is up on 39133
2022-07-19T05:22:15.187388+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-07-19T05:22:56.191917+00:00 app[web.1]: Sent: <ref *2> {
2022-07-19T05:22:56.191938+00:00 app[web.1]: resolve: [Function: resolve],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.191939+00:00 app[web.1]: normalize: [Function: normalize],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.191940+00:00 app[web.1]: isAbsolute: [Function: isAbsolute],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.191940+00:00 app[web.1]: join: [Function: join],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.191941+00:00 app[web.1]: relative: [Function: relative],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.191943+00:00 app[web.1]: toNamespacedPath: [Function: toNamespacedPath],  
2022-07-19T05:22:56.191943+00:00 app[web.1]: dirname: [Function: dirname],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.191943+00:00 app[web.1]: basename: [Function: basename],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.191943+00:00 app[web.1]: extname: [Function: extname],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.191944+00:00 app[web.1]: format: [Function: bound _format],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.191944+00:00 app[web.1]: parse: [Function: parse],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.191947+00:00 app[web.1]: sep: '/',
2022-07-19T05:22:56.191947+00:00 app[web.1]: delimiter: ':',
2022-07-19T05:22:56.191947+00:00 app[web.1]: win32: <ref *1> {
2022-07-19T05:22:56.191947+00:00 app[web.1]: resolve: [Function: resolve],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.191948+00:00 app[web.1]: normalize: [Function: normalize],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.191948+00:00 app[web.1]: isAbsolute: [Function: isAbsolute],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.191948+00:00 app[web.1]: join: [Function: join],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.191948+00:00 app[web.1]: relative: [Function: relative],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.191949+00:00 app[web.1]: toNamespacedPath: [Function: toNamespacedPath],  
2022-07-19T05:22:56.191949+00:00 app[web.1]: dirname: [Function: dirname],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.191949+00:00 app[web.1]: basename: [Function: basename],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.191949+00:00 app[web.1]: extname: [Function: extname],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.191949+00:00 app[web.1]: format: [Function: bound _format],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.191950+00:00 app[web.1]: parse: [Function: parse],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.191950+00:00 app[web.1]: sep: '\\',
2022-07-19T05:22:56.191950+00:00 app[web.1]: delimiter: ';',
2022-07-19T05:22:56.191950+00:00 app[web.1]: win32: [Circular *1],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.191950+00:00 app[web.1]: posix: [Circular *2],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.191951+00:00 app[web.1]: _makeLong: [Function: toNamespacedPath]
2022-07-19T05:22:56.191951+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-07-19T05:22:56.191951+00:00 app[web.1]: posix: [Circular *2],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.191951+00:00 app[web.1]: _makeLong: [Function: toNamespacedPath]
2022-07-19T05:22:56.191952+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-07-19T05:22:56.197762+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=dan-rose.herokuapp.com request_id=c9318026-c4f1-4b37-a93c-bb022b6e70f9 fwd="27.51.152.68" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=12ms status=200 bytes=2929 protocol=https
2022-07-19T05:22:56.640001+00:00 app[web.1]: Sent: <ref *2> {
2022-07-19T05:22:56.640008+00:00 app[web.1]: resolve: [Function: resolve],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.640009+00:00 app[web.1]: normalize: [Function: normalize],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.640009+00:00 app[web.1]: isAbsolute: [Function: isAbsolute],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.640010+00:00 app[web.1]: join: [Function: join],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.640010+00:00 app[web.1]: relative: [Function: relative],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.640011+00:00 app[web.1]: toNamespacedPath: [Function: toNamespacedPath],  
2022-07-19T05:22:56.640011+00:00 app[web.1]: dirname: [Function: dirname],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.640012+00:00 app[web.1]: basename: [Function: basename],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.640012+00:00 app[web.1]: extname: [Function: extname],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.640012+00:00 app[web.1]: format: [Function: bound _format],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.640013+00:00 app[web.1]: parse: [Function: parse],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.640013+00:00 app[web.1]: sep: '/',
2022-07-19T05:22:56.640013+00:00 app[web.1]: delimiter: ':',
2022-07-19T05:22:56.640014+00:00 app[web.1]: win32: <ref *1> {
2022-07-19T05:22:56.640014+00:00 app[web.1]: resolve: [Function: resolve],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.640014+00:00 app[web.1]: normalize: [Function: normalize],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.640015+00:00 app[web.1]: isAbsolute: [Function: isAbsolute],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.640015+00:00 app[web.1]: join: [Function: join],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.640015+00:00 app[web.1]: relative: [Function: relative],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.640015+00:00 app[web.1]: toNamespacedPath: [Function: toNamespacedPath],  
2022-07-19T05:22:56.640016+00:00 app[web.1]: dirname: [Function: dirname],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.640016+00:00 app[web.1]: basename: [Function: basename],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.640016+00:00 app[web.1]: extname: [Function: extname],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.640016+00:00 app[web.1]: format: [Function: bound _format],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.640017+00:00 app[web.1]: parse: [Function: parse],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.640017+00:00 app[web.1]: sep: '\\',
2022-07-19T05:22:56.640017+00:00 app[web.1]: delimiter: ';',
2022-07-19T05:22:56.640017+00:00 app[web.1]: win32: [Circular *1],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.640018+00:00 app[web.1]: posix: [Circular *2],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.640018+00:00 app[web.1]: _makeLong: [Function: toNamespacedPath]
2022-07-19T05:22:56.640019+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-07-19T05:22:56.640019+00:00 app[web.1]: posix: [Circular *2],
2022-07-19T05:22:56.640019+00:00 app[web.1]: _makeLong: [Function: toNamespacedPath]
2022-07-19T05:22:56.640019+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-07-19T05:22:56.642730+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=dan-rose.herokuapp.com request_id=0f81bb77-64a4-4450-9e5e-76fc143c1148 fwd="27.51.152.68" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=2929 protocol=https
```

Since the build is succeeding I think the problem may lie in a file path somewhere. I've read the express.static documentation and it's seems like my file paths are correct so I really cannot figure out how to fix this. Here is my index.js file:

```html
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, "client", "public");
const buildPath = path.join(__dirname, "client/build");

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(express.static(buildPath));
console.log(publicPath);
console.log(buildPath);
console.log(__dirname);
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(publicPath, "index.html"));
  console.log("Sent:", path);
});

app.listen(port, (err) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log(`Server is up on ${port}`);
});
```

I have been trying to figure this out, and I've looked at similar questions here on Stack Overflow but nothing has worked so far.

What can I try next?

Comment: Have a look at your browser console or network tab to see if you can see any errors.

Comment: I was finally able to get my app running on Heroku. The problem was res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client/public/index.html")); It should have been "client/build/index.html". I also removed /build from the client folder gitignore.